# Mongodb build github commit number

Tags: mongodb

How can we get the commitid from which mongodb build was generated from running mongodb. I know this information is available when there are any failures in mongodb and its gets logged as commit version or something in the logs. But i am not sure how we can fetch it using mongodb shell. Just to be clear I dont want mongodb version like 4.2.0 but looking for commit id like [56eeca07155e9d5db36934fdbdc36cc118e2c519](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/commit/56eeca07155e9d5db36934fdbdc36cc118e2c519)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is avaialble as part of

```
shard2:SECONDARY> db.serverBuildInfo()
```